# CSS content property

Tags: css

I want to write `\` slash as value in `content` property of CSS class but it is breaking single quotes so I am using `\\` (double slashes).

```
a:before {
    content: '\\';
}
```

Am I doing it right?

Comment: Yes on chrome it works but on android browser it doesn't.

Comment: Yes, it works: http://jsfiddle.net/jCgng/

Comment: Try `\5C` instead - by using the character code for it, it should remove any ambiguitiy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yea, you are doing it right. [**It works - example here**](http://jsfiddle.net/wUDTG/1/)

`\` is meant to escape things such as unicode symbols and [HTML entities](http://dualunit.ch/en/tools/cp1252-characters/). By putting a `\` in as content, it is essentially being ignored, thus you are required to put 2 in order for one to be rendered.

For instance, `content: "\2193";` renders a down arrow `↓`. Without the escape, you would otherwise just be rendering `2193`. [**Example here**](http://jsfiddle.net/wUDTG/)

Alternatively, you could add the `\` via `5C` which is an HTML entity for a `\`.

`content:'\5C'` would effectivly render a backslash. [**Example here**](http://jsfiddle.net/K8rTy/)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is correct. See here: http://www.merttol.com/articles/code/introduction-to-css-escape-sequences.html